# Multiple replies from server for one client request

Tags: asynchronous, client-server

This may be a dumb question - and the title may need to be improved...  I think my requirement is pretty simple:  I want to send a request for data from a client to a server program, and the server (not the client) should respond with something like "Received your request - working on it".  The client then does other work.  Then when the server has obtained the data, it should send an asynchronous message (a popup?) saying "I've got your data; click on ... (presumably a URL) to obtain data".  I have been assuming that the server could be written in Java and that client is html and JavaScript. I haven't been able to come up with a clean solution - help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to employ "Websocket Method" by using  "SuperWebSocket" for server side, and "WebSocket4Net" for client side. It is working perfectly for my current project.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the work invovles the server being asynchronous.  To do this you must

1. Have an ajax call to the server that starts a job and returns a confirmation the job has been started.
2. A page on the server that will return whether or not any jobs are complete for a user.
3. Have an ajax widget on your client side that pings that page on teh server every so often to see if any jobs have been completed.  And if so make a pop up.

This is the only way unless you use Flex data services.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this on the HTTP protocol? It sounds like you're talking about a web application here, but it's not clear from the question. If so, then there are a variety of techniques for accomplishing this using AJAX which collectively go under the name "Comet". Depending on exactly what you're trying to accomplish, a number of different implementation, on both the client and server side, may be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

for pure java i suggest something like jgroups (client+server are java)
for html, you should use ajax - there you have a timer that checks every X seconds

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you have an alternative technique to use: [Websockets](http://websocket.org/). These are used for server->client communication without polling or ajax-style delayed responses.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  Sounds like it was just a matter of waiting for appropriate technology to show up!  I have also been told recently that HTML5 addresses this problem - comments?

Comment: Websockets are a very new part of the big bundle that is called HTML5.